# Border-Radius & Overflow: Hidden

Tags: css, position, overflow, border-radius

I seem to be having a weird problem when using border-radius and overflow: hidden together, please see the picture for my problem.

As you can see in the bottom right the image doesn't expand to the very edge of the div and a little curve is visible, any help will be much appreciated.

I also have a live version here, problem can be seen near the bottom of the page: http://hasky.infinityfreeapp.com/

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HeQD.jpg)

```css
.content__card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 80em;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-height: 35em;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.content__card .info {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 1.5em 3em;
  height: auto;
}

.content__card .info h2 {
  font-family: "DemiBold", sans-serif;
}

.content__card .info p {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw, 1.4rem);
  font-family: "Medium", sans-serif;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.content__card a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0.6em 1.8em;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 1.4rem);
  font-family: "Medium", sans-serif;
}

.content__card img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30em;
}

.content__card__three {
  background: #7D44FD;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content__card content__card__three span-2">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Sekite mūsu</h2>
    <h2>Youtube kanalą!</h2>
    <a href="#">Youtube</a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5ZXj6fP.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Reece, welcome to SO! You need to place some code [reprex]. Don't make us guess what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is exactly, but this is the solution I can provide depending on what I understood.
added the basic styling and also remove some unnecessary code.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

.content__card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-height: 35em;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content__card .info {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 1.5em 3em;
  width: 20rem;
}

.content__card .info h2 {
  font-family: "DemiBold", sans-serif;
}

.content__card .info p {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw, 1.4rem);
  font-family: "Medium", sans-serif;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.content__card a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0.6em 1.8em;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 1.4rem);
  font-family: "Medium", sans-serif;
}

.content__card img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30em;
}

.content__card__three {
  background: #7d44fd;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content__card content__card__three span-2">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Sekite mūsu</h2>
    <h2>Youtube kanalą!</h2>
    <a href="#">Youtube</a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5ZXj6fP.png">
</div>
```

Comment: if you change the background back to white and check the corners, there are some pixels that seem to be part of the border which is the curve mentioned by OP

Comment: @AmalJossy I'm having the same problem, researching if anyone else have had the same problem.